# how to create customized marshalled output from JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I don't want to use XML file created by JAXB marshaller, can I customize it, so that i would give a preferrable format to marshal objects?

Comment: you mean that you want the marshaling output to be something else than xml?

Answer (score 1):

You can take JAXB's XML output and process it in a way you like, to achieve an alternative output.

XSLT, DOM, or something else...

XML is perfect to be further transformed!

Comment: +1 In fact you can use `JAXBSource` to take a JAXB object and run it straight through a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, no need to go via the XML stage.

Answer (score 0):

jaxb is related to XML ... if you need to customize the xml then you can use the Jaxb annotations
http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html